# Rows values as distinct comma separated values based on identifier

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table as shown below

```
ID|Name|Address|Pincode
I1|Ramesh|Hyderabad|1234
I2|Bhaskar|india|1234
I2|Bhaskar|srilnaka|124
I3|Prasad|india|1234
I3|Prasad|india|1235
I4|Chandu|malaysia|1236
I4|Veeru|india|1236
```

I am required only one row for each ID wise and name,address and pincode should be comma separated values of all rows group by ID.

I want to get out put as shown below

```
ID|Name|Address|Pincode
I1|Ramesh|Hyderabad|1234
I2|Bhaskar|india,srilnaka|1234,124
I3|Prasad|india|1234,1235
I4|Chandu,veeru|malaysia,india|1236
```

Help me oracle query for getting the desired result

Comment: Why are you required that? It makes no sense. The current data model makes much more sense than what you are "required". Did anyone explain WHY they require you to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function. You just have to group by id and apply this function to name, address and pincode